# rails admin can not search if total objects goes to more than 450 records on create new object screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am attempting to create a new object for the "Roster" model using Rails Admin. A "Roster" belongs to a "Team," so when creating a new "Roster," it is essential to select the specific team for which the roster is intended.

Currently, I can successfully search for teams in the database, but I encounter issues when trying to search for teams beyond the first 450 records. This limitation is affecting my ability to find and select teams when creating a new "Roster" in Rails Admin.

Model structure

```
    class Team < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :rosters
     end 
    class Roster < ApplicationRecord
       belongs_to :team
    end
```

I've noticed that the search functionality is managed by the gems/rails_admin-3.1.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.erb gem file. It appears that this file loads all the teams during the page load, but there seems to be a limitation where it loads only the first 450 records and skips the rest.

Is there anyone who could assist me in modifying this behavior to make it possible to search through all the available records?
Rails version: 7.0.x
Ruby version: 3.1.2

Comment: Show [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you take a look at the rails console after loading this page, you should see the plain SQL, search for the word LIMIT to see if something is limiting.

Comment: Yes, I see SQL Query, there no limit shown.

Comment: Thanks, on the console when you type something to search for a team do you see an error?

Comment: Thanks for support, @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba, I got the issue, as issue was due to extra white space in previous team names, actually it allow to search only via complete word instead of autocomplete, so if team is example "ABC " than it must be type "ABC ", not "ABC"